# When I run the shapiro.test code with group_by function I get an unsued error

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Here is the data frame and code in simplified form

```
Type <- c("Bark", "Redwood", "Oak")
size <- c(10,15,13)
width <- c(3,4,5)
Ratio <- size/width
df <- data.frame(Type, size, width, Ratio)
mutate(df, ratio_log = log10(Ratio))
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% shapiro.test(ratio_log)

# Error in shapiro.test(., ratio_log) : unused argument (ratio_log)
```

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `?shapiro.test`, we can see that the only possible argument is:

- `x`, a numeric vector of data values

Using the `%>%` operator, you can see that the output says

> Error in shapiro.test(., ratio_log) : unused argument (ratio_log)

Notice the dot before `ratio_log`. This means that `shapiro.test` has already considered `df` as its argument.

There is no need for a grouping for using `shapiro.test`. Also, you to use the column that you have created in `df`, you should write:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(df, ratio_log = log10(Ratio))
```

You can now use `shapiro.test` like

```
shapiro.test(df$ratio_log)
```

or

```
df$ratio_log %>% shapiro.test
```

Comment: I have a larger data frame that  consists of 10 types of trees and 800 rows of data for the ratio for each type, I am trying to graph each type of tree to see if the distribution I get is normal. So I need to use the group_by function to group the type column and test the individual trees themselves. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

the last sentence "shapiro.test(ratio_log)" should be changed by "shapiro_test(ratio_log)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try shapiro_test() instead of shapiro.test(),  it worked for me.

Comment: Hi map, welcome to SO. Before posting an answer, please check that your solution has not already been posted. Your answer is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378590/2530121. Thanks